# Using Allure report with Typescript

Tags: typescript, allure

How to use Allure report with Typescript? I tried but it doesn't work.

Error

```
Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'severity' of undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'severity' of undefined
```

config.ts

```
onPrepare: function () {
   const AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
   resultsDir: 'target/allure-report'
   }));
}
```

In spec files
`import { allure } from 'allure-js-commons';`

For example
`allure.severity(allure.SEVERITY.BLOCKER);`

I understand I do something wrong but what?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Please be more specific on the outcome of your code (compiler/runtime error messages) and what you expected to happen. Furthermore, we might not be able to reproduce the problem with only those portions of code, so making a [MCVE] is highly recommended.

Comment: @E_net4 added an error

Comment: I fixed this issue<br>
`import * as AllureReporter from 'jasmine-allure-reporter';`

But now I have another problem

  Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'BLOCKER' of undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'BLOCKER' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spec files should be `declare const allure: any;`